# Problemas en mysq: Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `netflix`.`lista` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

me tira el siguiente error, Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `netflix`.`lista` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Si borro la foreign key de idPerfil me deja crear la tabla, pero sino no, y no se que falla, intente de todo y no me deja, alguna idea de que puede ser?, gracias!

````
drop database netflix;
create database netflix;
use netflix;

create table Contenido(
idCont int not null,
duracion time not null,
categoria varchar(20) not null,
 primary key (idCont)
);

create table Usuarios(
 idUsuario int not null,
 mail varchar(50) not null,
 nombreYApellido varchar(50) not null,
 contraseña varchar(20) not null,
 primary key (idUsuario),
 unique(mail)
);

create table Perfiles(
idPerfil int not null,
idUsuario int not null,
primary key (idUsuario, idPerfil),
foreign key (idUsuario) references Usuarios(idUsuario)
);

create table Lista (
idPerfil int not null,
idCont int not null,
primary key ( idPerfil, idCont),
foreign key (idCont) references contenido(idCont), //esta linea no afecta en nada
foreign key (idPerfil) references Perfiles(idPerfil) //esta linea falla
);```
````

Comment: En la tabla `Perfiles` `idPerfil` no es un indice por si misma en dicha tabla. [Mas info aca](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no todas tus foraneas debes incluirlas como Primary Key, solo el id de la Tabla. Te dejo la correción aquí abajo. Saludos

```
create table Contenido(
idCont int not null,
duracion time not null,
categoria varchar(20) not null,
 primary key (idCont)
);

create table Usuarios(
 idUsuario int not null,
 mail varchar(50) not null,
 nombreYApellido varchar(50) not null,
 contraseña varchar(20) not null,
 primary key (idUsuario),
 unique(mail)
);

create table Perfiles(
idPerfil int not null,
idUsuario int not null,
primary key (idPerfil),
foreign key (idUsuario) references Usuarios(idUsuario)
);

create table Lista (
idPerfil int not null,
idCont int not null,
primary key ( idPerfil),
foreign key (idCont) references Contenido(idCont), 
foreign key (idPerfil) references Perfiles(idPerfil)

);
```